# Supplying UITableView Core Data the old-fashioned way

Tags: core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Does anyone have an example of how to *efficiently* provide a UITableView with data from a Core Data model, preferable including the use of sections (via a referenced property), *without* the use of NSFetchedResultsController?

How was this done before NSFetchedResultsController became available? Ideally the sample should only get the data that's being viewed and make extra requests when necessary.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Dare I ask **why** you wish to avoid using NSFetchedResultsController? I would infer from your italicization of "efficiently" that you either feel that NSFetchedResultsController seems inefficient somehow. Please explain?

Comment: I'd like to see an example that is efficient in the same way that NSFetchedResultsController is (i.e. only fetching the rows that are needed), however I can't use NSFetchedResultsController because I need to fudge the results by inserting extra rows that have nothing to do with the data model...

Comment: Well you could copy the fetched results array to an NSMutableArray then insert your fudged values wherever you need them, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I agree with CommaToast that there's at best a very limited set of reasons to implement an alternative version of `NSFetchedResultsController`. Indeed I'm unable to think of an occasion when I would advocate doing so.

That being said, for the purpose of education, I'd imagine that:

- upon creation, `NSFetchedResultsController` runs the relevant `NSFetchRequest` against the managed object context to create the initial result set;
- subsequently — if it has a delegate — it listens for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` from the managed object context. Upon receiving that notification it updates its result set.

Fetch requests sit atop predicates and predicates can't always be broken down into the keys they reference (eg, if you create one via `predicateWithBlock:`). Furthermore although the inserted and deleted lists are quite explicit, the list of changed objects doesn't provide clues as to how those objects have changed. So I'd imagine it just reruns the predicate supplied in the fetch request against the combined set of changed and inserted records, then suitably accumulates the results, dropping anything from the deleted set that it did previously consider a result.

There are probably more efficient things you could do whenever dealing with a fetch request with a fetch limit. Obvious observations, straight off the top of my head:

- if you already had enough objects, none of those were deleted or modified and none of the newly inserted or modified objects have a higher sort position than the objects you had then there's obviously no changes to propagate and you needn't run a new query;
- even if you've lost some of the objects you had, if you kept whichever was lowest then you've got an upper bound for everything that didn't change, so if the changed and inserted ones together with those you already had make more then enough then you can also avoid a new query.

The logical extension would seem to be that you need re-interrogate the managed object context only if you come out in a position where the deletions, insertions and changes modify your sorted list so that — before you chop it down to the given fetch limit — the bottom object isn't one you had from last time. The reasoning being that you don't already know anything about the stored objects you don't have hold of versus the insertions and modifications; you only know about how those you don't have hold of compare to those you previously had.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering, you deserve a tick for that :) Specifically the problem that I had was the need to support empty section; something that NSFetchedResultsController simply can't do. Since then I written my own subclass to patch in this feature - TAFetchedRestultsController on GitHub if you're interested.